# How to support piping in my function

Tags: powershell

I want to be able to use my function like:

```
Get-Process | export-xsl;
```

Right now I'm manually calling `Get-Process` inside my function:

```
function export-xsl() {
    $path = "{0}\Downloads\test.csv" -f $home;
    Get-Process | export-csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation
    Invoke-item $path;
}
```

The examples I found seem to iterate on each item, which I believe will create multiple .csv files.

**I tried, but this creates the CSV dozens of times,** once per iteration. I'm trying to get the entire object as one CSV file.

```
function export-xsl() {
    process {
        $path = "{0}\Downloads\test.csv" -f $home;
        $_ | export-csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation
        Invoke-item $path;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/12/31/write-powershell-functions-that-accept-pipelined-input/

Comment: There are several short answers on StackOverflow as well e.g. [How do you write a powershell function that reads from piped input?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11880114)

Comment: @4c74356b41, @wOxxOm: I tried both pages. They keep giving me multiple iterations (which creates a new CSV file, each time it only shows one result) This is different behavior than manually calling `Get-Process | export-csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation` **that creates one single CSV, with all processes in the same sheet**. I can't figure out how to use the entire piped input. -- I added my broken `process {}` code above.

Comment: Simplest, IMHO, to implement variant would be: `function export-xsl { $path = "{0}\Downloads\test.csv" -f $home; $input | export-csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation; Invoke-item $path }`. It is possible to do this without collecting all the input before exporting it to CSV, but it require more code and `SteppablePipeline` in particular.

Comment: That works! If you make it an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function export-xsl {
    $path = "{0}\Downloads\test.csv" -f $home;
    $input | export-csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation;
    Invoke-item $path;
}
```

`$input` will allow you to pipe all the data at once, instead of many iterations.